# Multiple matchcollections per line

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am parsing a text file line by line, how can I create multiple match collections and attempt multiple matches on each line processed?

Currently I am trying this:

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {

string match1 = @"\s+([^)]*):entry:\s+cust\(([^)]*)\)\s+custno\(([^)]*)\)\s+id\(([^)]*)\)\s+name\(([^)]*)\)";
string match2 = @"group\(([^)]*)\)\s+spec\(([^)]*)\)\s+goodtill([^)]*)$";
string match3 = @"returns\(([^)]*)\)";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(line, match1);
MatchCollection matches2 = Regex.Matches(line, match2);
MatchCollection matches3 = Regex.Matches(line, match3);




foreach (Match matchr1 in matches)
{

    line1.Add("Date:" + matchr1.Groups[1].Value + ", Customer:"
                    + matchr1.Groups[2].Value + ", CustID:" + matchr1.Groups[3].Value +
                    ", ID:" + matchr1.Groups[4].Value + ", Name:" + matchr1.Groups[5].Value);
}

foreach (Match matchr2 in matches2)
{

    line2.Add("Group:" + matchr2.Groups[1].Value + ", Spec:" + matchr2.Groups[2].Value + ", Good Till:" + matchr2.Groups[3].Value);
}

foreach (Match matchr3 in matches3)
{

    line3.Add("Returns: " + matchr3.Groups[1].Value);
}

}
```

After processing the file and trying to count the arraylist sizes:

```
MessageBox.Show(line1.Count + " " + line2.Count + " " + line3.Count);
```

I receive 5000 0 0. Why are my last 2 arraylists empty? There should be many matches, regexs are confirmed correct.

Sample data:

```
LUCIE:496 27AUG120755:entry: cust(GUIR) custno(j010705) id(293746) name(mike)
LUCIE:496 27AUG120755:       group(0000) spec(03) stripdn(N) pre228(N)       goodtill 01/MAR/08
LUCIE:496 27AUG120755:getprotcode given (m000029374603MAR08), returns (TUUjFDEO)
```

Comment: Because the second and third regular expressions are not matching at all? We can't give you a definite answer without knowing what your lines look like.  Did you even look at the contents of the reader and the collections to verify that you're getting the expected results? Why are you using ArrayLists?

Comment: Make sure that line still has content in it after the first call to Regex.Matches. Another thing I noticed on the API is that "The collection includes only successful matches and terminates at the first unsuccessful match.".. Could the method be terminating early? Can you give us the file you are testing this with? .... ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w.aspx

Comment: @Jeff confirmed regex in regexbuddy with associated lines. File containts confidential customer data, I will post sample data.

Comment: @Some Random Kid - No, there are problems with the last 2 regex's.

Answer (score 0):

If your going to be literal on the data, you must require the missing components in the 2nd and 3rd regex's. Or, if its variable, just add some fill `.*?`

```
 group
 \(
   ( [^)]* )
 \)
 \s+ spec
 \(
   ( [^)]* )
 \)
  # missing :
  #      \s+ stripdn
  #      \(
  #        ( [^)]* )
  #      \)
  #      \s+ pre228
  #      \(
  #        ( [^)]* )
  #      \)

 \s+ goodtill
 ( [^)]* )
 $


 returns
  # missing a \s* here
 \(
     ( [^)]* )
 \)


LUCIE:496 27AUG120755:entry: cust(GUIR) custno(j010705) id(293746) name(mike)
LUCIE:496 27AUG120755:       group(0000) spec(03) stripdn(N) pre228(N)       goodtill 01/MAR/08
LUCIE:496 27AUG120755:getprotcode given (m000029374603MAR08), returns (TUUjFDEO)
```